# Converting dates to periods - last saturday of each month sql

Tags: sql

Not a strong SQL user by any means. I'm trying to run a script that will return the fiscal period given the date of the transaction. The fiscal period is up to the last saturday of each month.

So for the year 2022, period 1 January would be Jan 1, 2022 to Jan 29,2022 (last saturday) and Feb would be Jan 30th to Feb 26, 2022 (last saturday). I need to run this script for multiple years.

Comment: I would recommend a lookup table with fiscal period ending dates in it. Save yourself the complicated where logic, user-defined functions, etc. (though that could be done).

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go, is it for MSSQL but would be pretty easy to flip around for many other DBMS.  Just that each is a little tricky with their own date/time syntax.  That being said the general concept should work for just about any of them as I'm not using anything unique to MSSQL.

```
DECLARE @DATE datetime
DECLARE @EOM datetime
DECLARE @SAT datetime
-- set a date to use
SET @DATE = '2022-06-28'
-- add a month 
SET @EOM = DATEADD(mm, 1, @DATE)
-- subtract the days to get last day of month

SET @EOM = DATEADD(dd, -DAY(@EOM), @EOM)
-- subtract days using weekday number to get Saturday

SET @SAT = DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @EOM))-1, @EOM)
-- display the result
SELECT @EOM as [EOM]
    , DATENAME(dw, @EOM) as [EOM_Day]
    , @SAT as [Last_Sat]
    , DATENAME(dw, @SAT) as [Last_day]
```

Although in my experience I would use this to create a calendar table of sorts.   It can be hard to use a function like this to `JOIN` to, etc.  But if you have the dates and results all stored out for the next 10 (or more) years it makes it much easier to use.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.